# Segmentation Fault when Creating an AVL Tree

Tags: c, tree, avl-tree

I'm attempting to create a basic AVL tree in C currently and I'm running into a strange problem. I've got a struct for the nodes of the tree, and a struct for the tree itself which contains a pointer to the root of the tree and the number of elements it has in it. I'm getting the seg. fault when I try to initialize the tree:

```
struct node{
    char *word;
    int balance;
    struct node *children[2];
};

struct tree{
    struct node *root;
    size_t numElements;
};

struct tree *treeCreate(void){
    struct tree *t;
    t->root = NULL;
    t->numElements = 0;
    return t;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct tree *t = treeCreate();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't think of the reason for this problem as I haven't even done anything with the pointers yet?

Comment: treeCreate should malloc t

Comment: Ah. Yes, I seem to have forgotten that. Simple mistake.